# Multiple identical forms sharing same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm a total newbie to JS/jQuery, so please, be gentle with me :).
Here is the problem i encounter on jsfiddler.net :
http://jsfiddle.net/_Arn__/n3oakxhd/2/

I have several identical forms on the same page, which sharing the same classes and the same structure, but with different numerical values. 
I've make a little script to do the math (a simple addition), but when i run the script, only the values of the first form are calculated, and results displayed on other forms are the one from the first one.

Is it possible to keep the same structure and to have specific results displayed for each form ?

```js
$( 'form' ).each(function(){ 
  var ligne_somme_1 = parseFloat($( ".ligne_somme_1" ).text()); 
 var ligne_somme_2 = parseFloat($( ".ligne_somme_2" ).text());
 var ligne_somme_3 = parseFloat($( ".ligne_somme_3" ).text());  
 var total= ligne_somme_1 + ligne_somme_2 + ligne_somme_3 ; 
 var afficheTotal = $( ".ligne_somme_4" );
     $( afficheTotal ).text( total) ;
});
```

```html
<form class="Aform">
  <li class="total_ligne_01 lignes">
    <div class="ligne_somme_1 lignes_somme">5$</div>
  </li>
  <li class="total_ligne_01b lignes">
+    <div class="ligne_somme_2 lignes_somme">5$</div> 
  </li>
  <li class="total_ligne_03 lignes">
  +  <div class="ligne_somme_3 lignes_somme">5.5$</div> = 
  </li>
  <li class="total_ligne_04 lignes">
    <div class="ligne_somme_4 lignes_somme"></div> 
  </li>
</form>

<hr />

<form class="Aform">
  <li class="total_ligne_01 lignes">
   <div class="ligne_somme_1 lignes_somme">10$</div>  
  </li>
  <li class="total_ligne_01b lignes">
 +   <div class="ligne_somme_2 lignes_somme">10$</div> 
  </li>
  <li class="total_ligne_03 lignes">
  +  <div class="ligne_somme_3 lignes_somme">10$</div> =
  </li>
  <li class="total_ligne_04 lignes">
    <div class="ligne_somme_4 lignes_somme"></div>
  </li>
</form>
```

Thank you for reading.
*Arn*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` reference inside `each` to reference current form:

```
$('form').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this); // Caching

    var ligne_somme_1 = parseFloat($this.find(".ligne_somme_1").text());
    var ligne_somme_2 = parseFloat($this.find(".ligne_somme_2").text());
    var ligne_somme_3 = parseFloat($this.find(".ligne_somme_3").text());
    var total = ligne_somme_1 + ligne_somme_2 + ligne_somme_3;

    $this.find(".ligne_somme_4").text(total);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/n3oakxhd/3/

Thanks to @plalx:

```
$('form').each(function() {
    var $lines = $(this).find('.lignes_somme'),
        total = 0;
    $lines.filter(':not(:last)').each(function() {
        total += parseFloat(this.textContent);
    });
    $lines.last().html(total);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/n3oakxhd/4/

Comment: My savior :)Thank you very much for your help, i knew it was something simple, but it took me so much time when i've trying to resolve it by myself.
Merci Tushar :)

Comment: Your code would be much better and more maintainable if you thought about being dynamic. `$('form').each(function () {
    var $lines = $(this).find('.lignes_somme'), total = 0;

    $lines.filter(':not(:last)').each(function () {
        total += parseFloat(this.textContent);
    });

    $lines.last().html(total);
});`

Comment: @plalx It totally depends on Arno. If he can change the forms structure as you've shown.

Comment: @Tushar There's really no reason not to be DRY here. Wheter the code changes or not, it's just a better practice. Anyway, who writes code that never changes?

Comment: Plalx : thank you for your response, i'll check this this evening.